# Javascript restlet api

Tags: restlet

When we look at the source code of the main page ot the restlet.org website, we may see the following :

```
type="text/javascript"     src="/javascript/restlet-client.js"
```

It seems you developped an api for javascript too? Couldn't it be proposed to the community too, and moreover with a typescript declation file to on github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score -1):

As koma said, this api is available and it targets both browsers and nodejs.

Thierry